# System Restore unable to complete due to missing .dll file?

Tags: windows-8.1, system-restore, dll

What had occured was that my friend was watching a video on Facebook through her Facebook wall, and suddenly the computer decided to restart. Then she got a screen saying:

> :(
>
> A problem has occured with your PC and needs restart. We will recompile information about your error and soon it will restart. (63% Complete)
>
> For more information, find out more about: BAD_POOL_HEADER

Then this occured:

> System restore could not extract the archive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\client\appvisvsubsystems32.dll) from the point of restoration. Error not specified during the execution of system restore. (0x80070017)

She has tried to click different restore points, and they all lead to the same error. She's also tried manually restarting the computer to no avail. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: What did you find when you searched "BAD_POOL_HEADER"?

Comment: @Xavierjazz According to several answers on answers.microsoft.com, it's due to a crash due to memory allocation.

Comment: 0x80070017 = CRC issue, so your restore data are corrupted. Run a HDD diag tool to check if the disk is fine

Comment: Boot via Hiren boot cd and run check disk. If you did not find any issues with HDD then back up your data and try reinstalling the OS.

Comment: So these things costs money? Should I just take it to a repair shop instead because I don't have an HDD diag tool nor the OS on a CD

Comment: @DonLarynx hiren's boot cd is free... However, repair shops can often be better